# Always return positive value

Tags: c#, math

I have a number it could be negative or positive but I simply want to return the positive value.

```
-4 -> 4
5 -> 5
```

I know I can do a simple if check, see if its zero then return it `*-1` but I can't remember for the life of me what the actual `Maths` operator is!

Can anyone tell me what it is?

Comment: It would have been quicker just to look at the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.aspx

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Use `System.Math.Abs` as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.abs).

Answer (score 11):

You're looking for `Math.Abs`.

Answer (score 10):

Use this :

```
int PositiveNo = System.Math.Abs(NegativeNoHere);
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an overloaded method [Math.Abs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.abs.aspx) can be used in your case. It can take `Double, Int16, Int32, Int64, SByte, Single or Decimal` as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with floats in Unity, use `Mathf.Abs`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.Abs` like `public static int Abs (int value);`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way with [Math.CopySign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.copysign?view=net-5.0):

```
var negativeNum = -5;
var positiveNum = Math.CopySign(negativeNum, 1); // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OutputNumber = System.Math.Abs(Input_Number)
```

Or

```
if(Input_Number<0){
return Input_Number=Input_Number * -1;
}else{
   return Input_Number;
}
```

Both should works fine

Comment: In your case if `num` is positive will become negative. The question ask for an absolute value. Please correct your answer.

Comment: correct, we can make multiplication with -1 as a condition like less than '0'. Thanks for highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Behind `System.Math.Abs`:

```cs
int abs(int value)
{
    if(value < 0)               // If value is negative
    {
        return value * -1;      // then return positive of value
    }
    return value;               // else return same value
}
```

Some fun mini Version:

```cs
int abs_mini(int value)
{
    return value < 0 ? value * -1 : value;
}
```

Lets use like that:

```cs
Console.WriteLine( abs(-3) );   // 3
Console.WriteLine( abs(-2) );   // 2
Console.WriteLine( abs(-1) );   // 1
Console.WriteLine( abs(0)  );   // 0
Console.WriteLine( abs(1)  );   // 1
Console.WriteLine( abs(2)  );   // 2
Console.WriteLine( abs(3)  );   // 3
```

Live action: https://rextester.com/OAAQ92244

Answer (score 0):

If you're using int or long, this is the fastest way I've found to force a positive value:

```
int negativeIntValue = -1234567890;
int positiveIntValue = negativeIntValue < 0 ? ~negativeIntValue + 1 : negativeIntValue;
// = 1234567890

long negativeLongValue = -1234567890;
long positiveLongValue = negativeLongValue  < 0 ? ~negativeLongValue + 1 : negativeLongValue ;
// = 1234567890
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to do this:

1. Built in function `Math.Abs(Int)`
2. Use `* -1` like `posNum *= - 1`